# Unnecessary space in an inline-blocks when line breaks

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to prevent the appearance of unnecessary space on the right of the inline-block when a line breaks? Here's my code for clarity

```css
.block1 {
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.block2 {
  width: 230px;
}

.main-text {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1">
  <span class="main-text">Main long text</span>
</div>
<div class="block2">
  <span class="main-text">Main long text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe you shoul use `min-width` but its not a good solution. What you want to do,totally?

Comment: Well, you are specifying that the element should be 230px wide, so which is it? 230px or the width of the content?

Comment: I have to add a symbol at right top outside the text block. It is adaptive page, so when width of block changes this problem appears. I tried flexboxes, absolute positioning, but haven't solved this problem yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a highlighter effect. Unfortunately, as `display: inline-block` draws a "box" around the element, it will not work. Instead, you can use `display: inline` to achieve what you want. Simply wrap the inner text with another `<span>` element, and say, give it a class of `.highlighter`:

```
<span class="main-text">
    <span class="highlighter">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
</span>
```

To *trick* the inline element to show left and right padding, you can simply draw a box-shadow around it. A box shadow on the left will have a negative x offset, e.g. `-10px 0 0 <color>`, while that on the right will have a positive x offset, e.g. `10px 0 0 <color>`:

```
.main-text .highlighter {
  background-color: rgb(50,50,50);
  color: white;
  display: inline;
  box-shadow:
    -10px 0 0 rgb(50,50,50),  /* Left box shadow */
    10px 0 0 rgb(50,50,50);   /* Right box shadow */
  padding: 10px 0;            /* Top and bottom paddings */
}
```

The positional arguments for [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) are:

1. `x-offset`
2. `y-offset`
3. `blur-radius`

A box shadow of `-10px 0 0 <color>` will generate a box shadow that is offset 10px to the left (creating an imaginary left padding, or extension of the background), with no y-offset and no blur. The converse is the same for `10px 0 0 <color>`.

Since the 10px box shadow will be outside the drawing box of the element, make sure you provide an appropriate padding/margin in the parent so that they do not get cut off.

See proof-of-concept example below:

```css
.block1 {
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 10px;  /* Give this the same value as the box-shadow offsets */
  background-color: steelblue; /* So you can see that the highlighter doesn't fall outside */
}
.main-text {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px; /* For presentational purposes only */
}
.main-text .highlighter {
  background-color: rgb(50,50,50);
  color: white;
  display: inline;
  line-height: 1.5;           /* Line height used so backgrounds don't overlap */
  box-shadow:
    -10px 0 0 rgb(50,50,50),  /* Left box shadow */
    10px 0 0 rgb(50,50,50);   /* Right box shadow */
  padding: 10px 0;            /* Top and bottom paddings */
}
```

```html
<div class="block1">
  <span class="main-text"><span class="highlighter">Lorem ipsum</span></span>
  
  <span class="main-text"><span class="highlighter">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span></span>
  
  <span class="main-text"><span class="highlighter">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, I am a very long title</span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.block1 {
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.block2 {
  width: 230px;
}

.main-text {
  display: inline;
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1">
  <span class="main-text">Main long text</span>
</div>
<div class="block2">
  <span class="main-text">Main long text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: i just changed your display property  ---> " display: inline; "